# will_paginate + ajax deletion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, will-paginate

I've got a list of resources that I show on a paginated list using [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate).

I haven't customized anything, here's my view:

```
<ul>
<%= render :partial => "item_li", :collection => @items%>
</ul>
<%= will_paginate @items %>
```

Items is calculated like this on the controller:

```
@items = Item.find(:all)
```

The generated code is a simple html list with the pagination navigation links at the bottom:

```
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
...
<li>Item 10</li>
</ul>
<div class="pagination">
  <span class="disabled prev_page">Previous</span>
  <span class="current">1</span>
  ...
</div>
```

I have included a "delete" button on my items. When that link is pressed, there's an ajax call to the server and the item disappears from the list (the `<li>` will is replaced by `""`)

My problem comes with the navigation links.

- Say that I had items 1 to 10 on the first page, items 11 to 20 on the second, etc.
- Say that I delete items 1, 2 and 3 on the first page.
- And then I press "next".

The server will "recalculate" the list of items; since I removed 3 of the previous list, it will return items 13 to 22. In other words, items 10, 11 and 12 don't appear on the first page nor the second.

How can I solve this in a simple, elegant way?

So far the only solution I could find was reloading the whole page after each deletion, but then using ajax becomes pointless.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to do something a bit simpler; whenever I deleted an item from the list, I loaded the item that came right after the last item on the page, and inserted it at the bottom. This way, I can delete to my heart's content, and the whole page feels snappy.

I just have to be careful with the "no more items" situations.

Thanks a lot for your answer, Zachary, but this one feels more correct.

Comment: hi @kikito, i'm in the same situation, please can you show me an example of what the code will look like

Comment: hi @medBo, I am sorry but I don't have access to that code any more.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your AJAX library, you need to implement a callback method that gets called whenever the AJAX call has completed successfully.

First, put the `<%= will_paginate @items %>` into a div or some sort of container. Then, in your "success" callback, remove that div and replace it with a new one containing a new call to will_paginate @items.

This works assuming that your AJAX call to your delete method reloads the @items variable.

If you're using jQuery, it'd look something like this (assuming you give the div holding the pagination a class called "my_pagination":

```
$.ajaxSuccess(function(){
  $(".my_pagination").text("");//Cleans out the div
  $(".my_pagination").append(<%=will_paginate @items%>);//Refill the div with a new pagination
});
```

You may have to wrap the <%=will_paginate @items%> in quotation marks, I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I finally did something different, but this helped me find the right solution. So +1!